# irony-mode in Windows OS

Tags: c++, c++11, emacs, mingw, emacs24

I'm interested to use [irony-mode](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode) in Windows, do you have a more detailed tutorial?

I tried using MinGW and the Guide [Wiki](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode/wiki/Setting-up-irony-mode-on-Windows-using-Msys2-and-Mingw-Packages)

But I get the following error:

> "Standard library doesn't support C++11!"

Comment: lol, it's enabled by default.

Comment: @MartinJames maybe that's the ironic bit? :)